# Not able to install c++ eclipse indigo after completely uninstalling

Tags: 11.10, installation, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I had installed Indigo eclipse successfully earlier in Ubuntu (Virtual Machine) with following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt
```

However, it got messed up when I did an update from its "Install New Software" tab. After running following commands, I removed eclipse completely.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge eclipse
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/eclipse /usr/lib/eclipse/ /usr/share/eclipse /usr/share/man/man1/eclipse.1.gz /etc/eclipse.ini
```

However, now I want to again install eclipse in my Ubuntu. When I run the above commands, it simply doesn't go well and stop at following execution:

```
milind@milind-VirtualUbuntuOneiric:~$ sudo apt-get install eclipse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  eclipse
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 147 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/17.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 131 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  eclipse
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Selecting previously deselected package eclipse.
(Reading database ... 133931 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking eclipse (from .../eclipse_3.7.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Setting up eclipse (3.7.0-0ubuntu1) ...
milind@milind-VirtualUbuntuOneiric:~$
```

Trying for so long (with restarting the VBox many times), but no luck. Can you please help me with:

1. How to install eclipse for C++ (I think indigo) from command line
   like earlier I did ?
2. If command line is not working then what is the latest C++ eclipse
   site to get it ?
3. How to install proper CDT for this eclipse so that it can be used
   nicely for debugging (which was my root problem) ?

Comment: I recommend installing eclipse from repo, but managing all plug-ins from within eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing about Eclipse IDE is that you don't need to install it. When you download Eclipse you get a zip file that you can unzip to somewhere in your home directory and just execute it from that directory.
If you will visit the [Eclipse downloads site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) you will see a list of available packages where you can choose the *Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers* (32/64 bit) and download the zip file.

You'll also get the latest version (v3.7.2) which is newer than what you'll find in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is:
download Eclipse **CDT** from Eclipse home page
un"zip" it in the folder X. Open Eclipse from folder X, choose workspace folder and that is it.